# insert data and array multidimensional

Tags: codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have an error when I am going to insert to database.

I have this array:

When I print_r($students) its structure is this:

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [lastname] => en [firstname] => estudianten [code] => U0009876 [id_estud] => 5 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [lastname] => Euno [firstname] => estudiante| [code] => U00020814 [id_estud] => 6 ) )

In my model I have this code:

```
function insert_register_students($students) {
        foreach ($students as $student) {
            foreach ($student['dates'] as $key => $value) {
                $data = array(
                    'field1' =>$student['id'],
                    'field2' => $key,
                    'field3' => '',
                );
                $this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the model how can I do reference that $students is a stdClass Object?  The last code in the model works well for me if $students is an array but now has stdClass Object.

What is my error?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: which error you see?
You do foreach ($student['dates'] as $key => $value) but in the array there are not 'dates'...

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  There is other array named dates_data, where for each students are registered many values for each date.

Comment: Have you tried the answers below?

Comment: Yes, I am trying.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you have an array of stdObject. On each iteration in the foreach you handle an object. So if you want to access its properties you have to do

```
'field1' => $student->property,
```

instead of

```
'field1' => $student['property']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
foreach ($students as $student) {
  echo $student->lastname; //and so on
}
```

Hope it helps